# Диалог. Проверьте задание, пожалуйста

Tags: прямая-речь, диалог

Какие диалоги оформлены правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой ответ: 1 и 3.

Comment: Никита, пожалуйста, прочитайте https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask и старайтесь вставлять не фотографии заданий, а переписывать их текст в тело вопроса: так другие посетители сайта смогут найти полезную для себя информацию.

Comment: Слишком много писать. И когда лепишь много писанины, то у многих отпадает интерес помочь. Мне бы просто хотелось проверить свой ответ.

Comment: Никита, это не сайт проверки домашних заданий. Это библиотека вопросов, ответы на которые могут помочь другим людям. В текущем виде ваши вопросы никому не помогут, потому что по картинкам поисковые системы страницы не индексируют (переводя в текстовый формат фото).

Answer (score 3):

Правильно оформлены диалоги: **1**, **2**, **5**.

**3-й диалог** должен быть оформлен так:

*«Я увижусь с вами до отъезда?» — спросила Маша. «Конечно, я рано встаю». — «Хорошо, спокойной ночи».*

**4-й диалог**:

*«Я готов», — заявил Вадик, выходя из палатки. «Ты замёрзнешь, — предупредил его следопыт. — Может быть, оденешься потеплее?» — «Я же двигаться буду».*

[**§ 52. Знаки препинания при диалоге**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154) (справочник Розенталя)

> 2. Если реплики следуют **в подбор**, без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней **тире**:
>
> *«Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет». — «На ком?» — «На Лариной». — «Татьяне?» — «Ты ей знаком?» — «Я им сосед»* (П.).
>
> 3. Если после реплики **идут слова автора**, то перед следующей репликой **тире опускается**:
>
> *«Не видать?» — повторил барин. «Не видать», — вторично ответствовал слуга* (Т.).